# how do i set the destination only flag for the AODv protocol in the ns2 environment

Tags: c++, ns2

in our protocol implementation the intermediate nodes must not respond to the RREQ it receives. i am working in an NS2 environment and want to know what changes to make in the existing AODV protocol code and where to make it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying sendRREP() function in aodv.cc(ns2.xx/aodv) file..